# Printing uint256 value to console while debugging with Truffle

Tags: solidity, truffle, contract-debugging, truffle-contract, truffle-migration

I am trying to figure out how to print values to the console while doing `truffle debug <txhash>`.  So far I have tried using an event called "TestValue", but I am not seeing the output in the console window like so.  Does anybody have any insight as to how I can print out a numeric value to the console?  I have also looked into logx, such as doing `log0(uint256Value)` but saw that that is looking for bytes instead of a uint256.

This is the TestValue event that I tried that is not printing the output I am looking for:

[image]

Which is the method that I believe is making my contract fail like so:

[image]

Greatly appreciate in advance if somebody can help me to see the values being compared in that condition!

Answer (score 2):

Now you can easily see the state of local variables pressing `v` during the debug. Also, you can see specific expression using the `watch` function.

For more information please read the following very good Truffle tutorial: [*Variable Inspection: going deeper with the truffle solidity debugger*](https://truffleframework.com/tutorials/debugger-variable-inspection)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the value of a function that return uint256, try

```js
(await [the function that return uint256]()).toString()
```

Uint256 is a kind of number but it is only ready to be displayed as string.
On blockchain, every method is asynchronous, remember to add `await` before each method so that you can pipeline the result