# Truffle console: How to print uint array

Tags: solidity, truffle, arrays

How to print uint array in Truffle's Java script environment?

Hi,

I am following the link:
[Printing uint256 value to console while debugging with Truffle](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/33137/printing-uint256-value-to-console-while-debugging-with-truffle)

I am working on truffle console environment which uses javascript code. I want to print the return value of an uint array as returned by the following Solidity code:

```
 pragma solidity ^0.5.0; 
   
// Creating a contract
contract Typespop { 
 
    // Defining an array
    uint[] data
      = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50];
   
    // Defining a function to
    // pop values from the array
    function array_pop(
    ) public returns(uint[] memory){ 
        data.pop();
        return data; 
    } 
}
```

I have tried the following:

truffle(development)> (await vic.array_pop()).toString()
'[object Object]'
truffle(development)>

Somebody please guide me.
@Phạm Huy Phát, please guide me.

Zulfi.

Answer (score 0):

A problem with your contract is that `array_pop` modifies the storage so you will get a transaction receipt as the return value and not the array.

```
function view_array(
) public view returns(uint[] memory){ 
    return data; 
}
```

Then you can do something like this

```bash
truffle(develop)> vic = await Test.deployed()

## [...very long output of the contract object...]

truffle(develop)> await vic.array_pop()

## [...very long output of the transaction receipt...]

truffle(develop)> arr = await vic.view_array()

## Now `arr` contains the array that you can inspect

truffle(develop)> arr.forEach((item) => console.log(item.toString()))
```